# How do I return Multiple String from loops?

Tags: java, return

Please take a look at this code (*with ArrayList implementation*)

```
public String returnCoreUnitsForProgram()
{
    ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProgramClass pc = new ProgramClass("","","","");

    if ( pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology")
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Network Technology" )
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Games Technology" ) )
    {                           
       for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size() ; i++)
       {
            if (UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core"))
                testArray.add( UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName() );
       }                
    }  

    return testArray;
}
```

With ArrayList - I get the error "**imcompatible types**"

Without ArrayList:

```
public void returnCoreUnitsForProgram()
{               
    ProgramClass pc = new ProgramClass("","","","");

    if ( pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology")
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Network Technology" )
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Games Technology" ) )
    {                           
       for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size() ; i++)
       {
            if (UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core"))
            UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName();
       }                
    }                  
}
```

In another class "ProgramClass",

```
public String programToString()
{
    Apps apps = new Apps();
    String str = "Program Code: " + getProgramCode()
                +"\nProgram Code: " + getProgramName()
                +"\nProgram Major: "+ getProgramMajor()
                + apps.returnCoreUnitsForProgram();
    return str;
}
```

I can't possibly do this because `returnCoreUnitsForProgram()` method is void.

So I'm thinking that my only option is to use the first implementation method with ArrayList.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: return a list of strings.

Comment: of course you have to use the arraylist or an array of strings

Comment: Read a book about java or programming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to return an `ArrayList`, but you're returning a `String`. Change the function definition to

```
public ArrayList<String> returnCoreUnitsForProgram()
```

Also, you may want to do a lot more reading up on Java core concepts.

Answer (score 1):

In the top most example the method is declared to return a `String`, while you are attempting to return an `ArrayList` from the method body. May I suggest that you alter the declaration of the method to return `List<String>` instead, it should work (compile).

Thus;

```
public List<String> returnCoreUnitsForProgram(){

    ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProgramClass pc = new ProgramClass("","","","");

    if ( pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology")
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Network Technology" )
      || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Games Technology" ) )
    {                           
       for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size() ; i++)
       {
            if (UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core"))
                testArray.add( UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName() );
       }                
    }  

    return testArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with Arraylist implementation. Also in your programToString() method , iterate your list and append to String

```
 public List<String> returnCoreUnitsForProgram()
  {
   ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    ProgramClass pc = new ProgramClass("","","","");

   if ( pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Software Technology")
  || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Network Technology" )
  || pc.getProgramMajor().equals("Games Technology" ) )
 {                           
   for(int i = 0; i< UnitArray.size() ; i++)
   {
        if (UnitArray.get(i).getUnitType().equals("Core"))
            testArray.add( UnitArray.get(i).getUnitName() );
   }                
}  

return testArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change method type from `String` to `ArrayList<String>` :)